# how to solve this kotlin plugin problem in android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I cloned this udacity project and seems to have an earlier version of kotlin plugin and gradle. all good until i add a new fragment so when the gradle sync it shows this error

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.component.AmbiguousConfigurationSelectionException: Cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10:

- gradle70JavadocElements
- gradle70RuntimeElements
- gradle70SourcesElements
- javadocElements
- runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
- sourcesElements

PS: Im new to android development

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try downgrade version?

In your build.gradle(project level), downgrade from 1.7.10 to 1.6.21
Like this:

```
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21'
```

Comment: Thanks that really worked i didn't think it would be the version of plugin thank you again

Comment: Hi Tocklewo, if my answear is helpful, please accept it.

Comment: hey im really sorry this is my first time here XD, thanks